# How to use a <div> tag instead of <iframe> to load a Spry vertical menu?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dreamweaver, innerhtml

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer. I have searched for weeks on this topic and cannot find anything that will work.

I'm in charge of updating an online resource guide for employees at my office. My work uses a proprietary web software called InQuira Info Manager for people to search the repository for answers. Basically it works like WordPress. It's a web-based WSYIWYG web editor, but you can add source code manually as well.

At work, I use Dreamweaver CS2 [upgrading is not a current option] and all our machines have IE7—I have no idea for how much longer. So, whatever I build has to be compatible with IE7 and cannot be a data-driven site, such as using PHP or other server-side technologies. I can, however, use JavaScript, whether referenced externally or inline.

The pages used for the reference guide are a two-colum format, with a left sidebar `<div>` for navigation and a right main `<div>` to display the content. I pulled the source code for a Spry vertical flyout menu from my copy of Dreamweaver CS6 at home and pasted it into my CS2 pages at work, inside a "#nav" `<div>` within the sidebar `<div>`.

Here's the problem: I need to be able to have the source HTML for the Spry menu file loaded into the `<div>`, rather than pasted in many different instances across multiple pages. As this is a resource guide, it will be regularly updated, so if I add or remove a topic, I don't want to have to do so twenty times, once for each topic. Template layouts will not work either, since I can't just hit the "re-publish" button in Dreamweaver—with Info Manager, I have to copy the entire HTML file's source code and manually paste it into the Info Manager file, sort of like creating a new WordPress entry.

I have tried using an `<iframe>` with no end of trouble; specifically, at least in IE7 `<iframe>` tags do not appear to respect the z-Index property and so no matter what, the flyout menus fall behind the content `<div>`. No matter what I do, I can't get them on top of the content . I have read about using JavaScript to use the `.innerHTML` property to load the content into the "#nav" `<div>` but I must be doing something wrong. I paste the script code within the `<head>` area and call the script within the HTML file, but can't get it to work.

I will admit that I'm certainly no pro when it comes to web design, but everything was going great until I hit this wall. IE7 sucks but I can't compel my work to upgrade. Any workaround ideas using JavaScript or other non-server-side alternatives would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Your explanation is a little long and I can't get what exactly the problem is (IE7 itself is a big problem :(). Are you trying to load a html file (or part of it) inside a div after a page loads? If so I can give you an example on how do it with jQuery (a Javascript library)

Comment: @Roimer, thanks for your response. I'm open to any suggestions you have. The long and short of it is that if I add a section or subsection to the site (the reference guide), I don't want to have to make the change across multiple instances of the same Spry menu. I want one external menu file that I can change once and have the change take effect on every page. Frameset is not an option, and iframes create no end of problems. Another site at my work seems to just use <script src="menu.txt"> with the actual HTML source for its menu stored in a separate window enclosed in document.write('...');.

Comment: Hi, I fixed your question's formatting, you can't use `<` or `>` unless they are _escaped_ (html entities), between _backticks_, or inside _<pre>_ or _<code>_ tags. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). And about your question, I have a possible answer (give me 10 min), but you should know that users usually are more interested in helping if you show them some code. If you don't show what have you tried they will ask you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

First, the iFrame: iFrames won't work in your case (in any browser AFAIK), because not matter what z index you set, the content inside the iFrame will never *overflow* outside of it; so, if your menu as a drop down submenu, it will be hidden *inside* the iFrame.

About the `document.write('...')` approach: I personally don't like using `document.write()`, since I feel that it makes code a little messy, because it requires placing the code embebed inside the html.

Your other approach was right: save the content of the Spry menu in a HTML file (with no head or body, just the content of the div). Add a `<div id='nav'>` tag where your menu is going to be shown (add all the external CSS needed for the menu too); then, add next Javascript inside the Head of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadSidebar()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            //Modern browsers (including IE8+, not sure if IE7)
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{//IE7, IE6 and IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {   //This will reemplace the content of the #Nav div 
                document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","SidebarMenu.html",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

And this just before the closing tag `</body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadSidebar();
 </script>
```

If this works, you may want to put the function that is on the head inside a external Javascript file (so you don't have the code in every page), and just kept the calling at the end of the body.

If it doesn't work I would recommend you to test it in Google chrome, with the console open (press `F12`, you may need to press `F5` once too), and add some `console.log()` calls inside the function, so you'll know where exactly the problem is. Fix it and then test it again in IE.